Seeking Numbers of Non-negative Integral solution pairs for $ax+by=n$
This is a problem from Polya's Problems and Theorems in Analysis I of the following format:

It happens to have a Cf. to solution but I cannot find it anyhow. 
I also happen to find a similar question here, which I think can be improved with the proposal of my question here. Similar Question Since there were no rigorous proof given there.
My attempt
I think we can simply put it in the generating function $$\frac{1}{(1-\xi ^a)(1-\xi^b)}$$ and then find the coefficient of the power of $n$ in the power series of $\frac{1}{(1-\xi^a)(1-\xi^b)}$
I separated the cases into 1. odd, even. 2. even, even. 3. odd,odd. And the even even case would give a gcd greater than $1$ so it could be ignored.(Cf. Lucenaposition's comment; editted after the proposal)But the computation is too huge that I could not manage.
Can anyone give me some guidance on evaluation of this series? Though, it might be wrong approach? Or, if you can find a link for the paper, please let me know.
Edit:
The question had been resolved with @MikeEarnest's "filling the gory" answer here: Answer

The even, even case means $\gcd(a,b)\ge2$ so it can be ignored.

The way I'd prove it is 1/ Clearly for $ 0 \leq n < ab$, there is 0 or 1 solutions. 2/  $n$ has $k$ solutions iff $n-ab$ has $k-1$ solutions. This idea is also represented in Thomas's writeup.

You say there were no rigorous proofs given to the old question, so I posted a new answer there which has a rigorous proof.

Also related

The generating function approach is good.
You can write:
$$\frac1{(1-x^a)(1-x^b)}=\frac{\left(1+x^a+x^{2a}+\cdots+x^{(b-1)a}\right)\left(1+x^{b}+x^{2b}+\cdots+x^{(a-1)b}\right)}{(1-x^{ab})^2}$$
Then use $\frac{1}{(1-y)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)y^n$ with the special case $y=x^{ab}.$
Then show that every coefficient in the numerator is $0$ or $1$ if $\gcd(a,b)=1.$
It takes a little more than that. If the coefficient of $x^n$ and $x^m$ are both $1$ for $m\neq n$ then $m\not\equiv n\pmod{ab}.$

I don't see how did you get the factorization formula. Could you demonstrate a few more steps?

Never mind, I think I got the gist of it

The last sentence could be strengthen to: For $ 0 \leq n < ab$, the coefficient of $x^n$ $ = 1 - $ the coefficient of $x^{n+ab}$.

How to show "Every coefficient in the numerator is $0$ or $1$ if $\gcd (a,b)=1$?" I don't quite have an idea.

I'm not giving you everything, sorry. @mathphysicist9283

I see. @ThomasAndrews No worries.

I'll give a hint, though, the coefficient of $x^m$ in the numerator is the number of solutions to $ax+by=m$ where $0\leq x<b, 0\leq y<a.$ Can there be more than one solution? @mathphysicist9283
